# Error executing Jupyter command 'kernel-gateway': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, jupyter, jupyter-kernel-gateway

I have python 3.7 installed in my macbook at /usr/local/opt/python@3.7/bin/python3.7. while my jupyter and kernel_gateway and all other packages are installed in /Users/user/Library/Python/3.7/bin/.

While trying to run

```
jupyter kernelgateway --api='kernel_gateway.notebook_http' -- 
KernelGatewayApp.seed_uri='./api.ipynb'jupyter kernelgateway -- 
api='kernel_gateway.notebook_http' --KernelGatewayApp.seed_uri='./api.ipynb'
```

command in my project terminal I get the following error: **Error executing Jupyter command 'kernelgateway': [Errno 2] No such file or directory.**
How should I go about this issue? Please help me out.

PS: I have added both the paths to the PATH variable